# How To Query A Repeated String Field With Empty Value [] in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

New to the BigQuery, I have a repeated field in BigQuery, like this

```
myTable
{
"id": 12345
"myNestedStringArrayField": []
}
```

How can I query all rows with the myNestedStringArrayField value is empty?
I tried using `myNestedStringArrayField is null`, but return no results, I know I have rows that have [] as the value. I also tried using the `= '[]'` , but the query edit throws an error.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using ARRAY_LENGTH, all rows you are seeking have a myNestedStringArrayField with a length of zero:

```
WITH sample AS(
    SELECT STRUCT("12345" AS id, [] AS myNestedStringArrayField) AS myTable
)

SELECT *
FROM sample 
WHERE ARRAY_LENGTH(myTable.myNestedStringArrayField) = 0
```

This returns:

[image]